# Clicar em link destacar SVG

Tags: javascript, svg

Estou aprendendo a lidar com SVG,

Minha duvida e a seguinte, tenho 10 bolinhas em SVG  e 10 links. Minha idéia e clicar em um link e destacar uma bolinha tirando o destaque das outras.

Comment: Coloca o código que você está trabalhando na Pergunta.

Answer (score 6):

<sup>Para efeitos de demonstração de como atingir o que pretendes, entende-se por "Destacar" o ato de dar uma cor diferente ao circulo em questão.</sup>

De forma a criar o teu contexto, vamos utilizar a seguinte *markup* onde temos um SVG com 10 círculos:

```html
<svg id="circulos" width="720" height="120">
    <circle id="circle0" cx="20" cy="60" r="10"></circle>
    <circle id="circle1" cx="60" cy="60" r="10"></circle>
    <circle id="circle2" cx="100" cy="60" r="10"></circle>
    <circle id="circle3" cx="140" cy="60" r="10"></circle>
    <circle id="circle4" cx="180" cy="60" r="10"></circle>
    <circle id="circle5" cx="220" cy="60" r="10"></circle>
    <circle id="circle6" cx="260" cy="60" r="10"></circle>
    <circle id="circle7" cx="300" cy="60" r="10"></circle>
    <circle id="circle8" cx="340" cy="60" r="10"></circle>
    <circle id="circle9" cx="380" cy="60" r="10"></circle>
</svg>
```

E os respetivos 10 botões para a troca de cor:

```html
<div>
    <button onclick="destacar('circle0')">0</button>
    <button onclick="destacar('circle1')">1</button>
    <button onclick="destacar('circle2')">2</button>
    <button onclick="destacar('circle3')">3</button>
    <button onclick="destacar('circle4')">4</button>
    <button onclick="destacar('circle5')">5</button>
    <button onclick="destacar('circle6')">6</button>
    <button onclick="destacar('circle7')">7</button>
    <button onclick="destacar('circle8')">8</button>
    <button onclick="destacar('circle9')">9</button>
</div>
```

[image: Pré-visualização da markup]

Cada botão ao ser clicado vai chamar a função de JavaScript `destacar(idDoCirculo)` que recebe como parâmetro uma `string` cuja mesma equivale ao `id` do circulo que pretendemos destacar:

```js
function destacar (id) {

    // Remover classe "destaque"
    var circulos = document.getElementById("circulos").getElementsByTagName('circle');
    for (var i=0; i < circulos.length; i++) {
        if (circulos[i].classList.contains('destaque')) {
            circulos[i].removeClass('destaque');
        }
    }

    // Adicionar classe "destaque" a quem diz respeito
    var svg = document.querySelector('#circulos #'+id);
    svg.addClass('destaque');
}
```

Dentro da função vamos a todos os círculos e retiramos a classe `destaque` se a mesma existir. Após isso vamos ao elemento indicado e adicionamos-lhe a classe `destaque`.

Desta forma ao clicar num botão estamos a destacar um circulo e a remover o destaque de todos os outros, indo assim ao encontro do que pretendes.

[image: Pré-visualização de botão clicado]

```js
function destacar (id) {

    // Remover classe "destaque"
    var circulos = document.getElementById("circulos").getElementsByTagName('circle');
    for (var i=0; i < circulos.length; i++) {
        if (circulos[i].classList.contains('destaque')) {
            circulos[i].removeClass('destaque');
        }
    }

    // Adicionar classe "destaque" a quem diz respeito
    var svg = document.querySelector('#circulos #'+id);
    svg.addClass('destaque');
}


// Tem classe
SVGElement.prototype.hasClass = function (className) {
  return new RegExp('(\\s|^)' + className + '(\\s|$)').test(this.getAttribute('class'));
};

// Adicionar Classe
SVGElement.prototype.addClass = function (className) {
  if (!this.hasClass(className)) {
    this.setAttribute('class', this.getAttribute('class') + ' ' + className);
  }
};

// Remover Classe
SVGElement.prototype.removeClass = function (className) {
  var removedClass = this.getAttribute('class').replace(new RegExp('(\\s|^)' + className + '(\\s|$)', 'g'), '$2');
  if (this.hasClass(className)) {
    this.setAttribute('class', removedClass);
  }
};

// Alternar Classe
SVGElement.prototype.toggleClass = function (className) {
  if (this.hasClass(className)) {
    this.removeClass(className);
  } else {
    this.addClass(className);
  }
};
```

```css
circle{
    fill:steelblue;
}
.destaque{
    fill:darkgoldenrod;
}
```

```html
<svg id="circulos" width="720" height="120">
    <circle id="circle0" cx="20" cy="60" r="10"></circle>
    <circle id="circle1" cx="60" cy="60" r="10"></circle>
    <circle id="circle2" cx="100" cy="60" r="10"></circle>
    <circle id="circle3" cx="140" cy="60" r="10"></circle>
    <circle id="circle4" cx="180" cy="60" r="10"></circle>
    <circle id="circle5" cx="220" cy="60" r="10"></circle>
    <circle id="circle6" cx="260" cy="60" r="10"></circle>
    <circle id="circle7" cx="300" cy="60" r="10"></circle>
    <circle id="circle8" cx="340" cy="60" r="10"></circle>
    <circle id="circle9" cx="380" cy="60" r="10"></circle>
</svg>
<div>
    <button onclick="destacar('circle0')">0</button>
    <button onclick="destacar('circle1')">1</button>
    <button onclick="destacar('circle2')">2</button>
    <button onclick="destacar('circle3')">3</button>
    <button onclick="destacar('circle4')">4</button>
    <button onclick="destacar('circle5')">5</button>
    <button onclick="destacar('circle6')">6</button>
    <button onclick="destacar('circle7')">7</button>
    <button onclick="destacar('circle8')">8</button>
    <button onclick="destacar('circle9')">9</button>
</div>
```

## Considerações

Para tornar a manipulação de classes nos elementos `circle` dentro do `svg` mais ágil, foram utilizados 4 métodos que ficam "pendurados" no protótipo de construção do elemento SVG para que todos os nós <sup>(nodes)</sup> do mesmo disponham de:

```
┌─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│ Método        │ Função                                  |
├─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ `hasClass`    │ Verifica se tem determinada classe      |
├─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ `addClass`    │ Adiciona determinada classe             |
├─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ `removeClass` │ Remove determinada classe               |
├─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ `toggleClass` │ Alternar presença de determinada classe |
└─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
```

Estes métodos são explicados em detalhe neste artigo da autoria de [Todd Motto](http://toddmotto.com/):

[Hacking SVG, traversing with ease - addClass, removeClass, toggleClass functions](http://toddmotto.com/hacking-svg-traversing-with-ease-addclass-removeclass-toggleclass-functions/)

Cada um dos referidos métodos encontra-se no trecho de código que pode ser visualizado e executado diretamente na resposta bem como no JSFiddle em baixo referenciado.

---

Exemplo também disponivel no [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zuul/xt7goLvd/).